# Layering images with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to create the following (mockup) with Bootstrap
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkgBu.jpg

The idea is that each of those squares is an image and I'll have Javascript control when they appear/disappear when the background image is clicked. What I'm having trouble with is getting the little squares to stack on top like I have it. I've done research here, tried a bunch of things on my own, but get close but no cigar.

This is the closest I've come (testing with 1 row first).
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqTc1.jpg

The squares line up next to eachother pretty well however they aren't showing within the same grid column/row correctly.

**Relevant HTML:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-centered">
    <div class="row row-centered">
        <div class="col-">
            <img src="resources/images/grey.jpg" class="character-img" onclick="StockCount();" />
            <img src="resources/images/blue.jpg" class="stock-img">
            <img src="resources/images/blue.jpg" class="stock-img">
            <img src="resources/images/blue.jpg" class="stock-img">
            <img src="resources/images/blue.jpg" class="stock-img">
            <img src="resources/images/blue.jpg" class="stock-img"> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-">
            <img src="resources/images/grey.jpg" class="character-img">

        </div>
        <div class="col-">
            <img src="resources/images/grey.jpg" class="character-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-">
            <img src="resources/images/grey.jpg" class="character-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-">
            <img src="resources/images/grey.jpg" class="character-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-">
            <img src="resources/images/grey.jpg" class="character-img">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-centered">
        <div class="col- col-centered">
            <img src="resources/images/grey.jpg" class="character-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-">
            <img src="resources/images/grey.jpg" class="character-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-">
            <img src="resources/images/grey.jpg" class="character-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-">
            <img src="resources/images/grey.jpg" class="character-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-">
            <img src="resources/images/grey.jpg" class="character-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-">
            <img src="resources/images/grey.jpg" class="character-img">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.character-img{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}

.stock-img{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 20;
}
```

EDIT:
Updated version yields slightly better results? Included adding the blue boxes to the second row.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-centered">
    <div class="row row-centered">
        <div class="col-2">
            <img src="resources/images/grey.jpg" class="character-img" onclick="StockCount();" />
            <img src="resources/images/blue.jpg" class="stock-img">
            <img src="resources/images/blue.jpg" class="stock-img">
            <img src="resources/images/blue.jpg" class="stock-img">
            <img src="resources/images/blue.jpg" class="stock-img">
            <img src="resources/images/blue.jpg" class="stock-img"> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <img src="resources/images/grey.jpg" class="character-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <img src="resources/images/grey.jpg" class="character-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <img src="resources/images/grey.jpg" class="character-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <img src="resources/images/grey.jpg" class="character-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <img src="resources/images/grey.jpg" class="character-img">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-centered">
    <div class="row row-centered">
        <div class="col-2">
            <img src="resources/images/grey.jpg" class="character-img" onclick="StockCount();" />
            <img src="resources/images/blue.jpg" class="stock-img">
            <img src="resources/images/blue.jpg" class="stock-img">
            <img src="resources/images/blue.jpg" class="stock-img">
            <img src="resources/images/blue.jpg" class="stock-img">
            <img src="resources/images/blue.jpg" class="stock-img"> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <img src="resources/images/grey.jpg" class="character-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <img src="resources/images/grey.jpg" class="character-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <img src="resources/images/grey.jpg" class="character-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <img src="resources/images/grey.jpg" class="character-img">
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <img src="resources/images/grey.jpg" class="character-img">
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.character-img{
position: relative;
z-index: 10;
}

.stock-img{
position: relative;
z-index: 20;
}
```

Result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPna5.jpg

Comment: So at first glance I notice you're using `col-` which... is not correct. In Bootstrap 4 you can use `col` but otherwise it needs to be followed by `-{NUM}` or `-{BREAKPOINT}-{NUM}` such as `'col-4` or `col-md-4`.  It's also not clear what you're doing to achieve the 'stacked' effect you want, as you're not using `position:absolute` anywhere and do not have nested content.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, when I tried using "position: absolute" I got mixed results, on the blue box it stacks them all on top of eachother.

.character-img{
 position: relative;
 z-index: 10;
}

.stock-img{
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 20;
}

https://imgur.com/xZeV7aI


Also when I use "col" instead of "col-" it gets really weird:
https://imgur.com/RzPZEaj

Did I misunderstand the documentation? I assumed "col-" was auto https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: Edit: I see you're supposed to supply a number to know how many our of 12 columns you want yours to use. I switched it to col-2 and it looks the same now.

Comment: See my edited description for what it looks like now based on some of the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Based on the images you've shown us to depict your desired outcome, I think Bootstrap is a smart choice. Much of what you want to do in your layout can be achieved using native classes.  But it's also pretty apparent that you lack a fundamental understanding of the Bootstrap Framework, and I would strongly encourage you to revisit their documentation.

A full example of the structure you're trying to achieve can be viewed at: https://www.bootply.com/SwuSKmlKWe

But let's look at the HTML of a single 'box' item:

```
<div class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 mb-4">
  <div class="h-100 bg-secondary p-4">
    <img src="//placehold.it/200x200" class="rounded-circle img-fluid d-block mx-auto" />

    <div class="row mt-4">
      <div class="col-3 text-center mb-2"><img src="//placehold.it/50x50" class="img-fluid" /></div>
      <div class="col-3 text-center mb-2"><img src="//placehold.it/50x50" class="img-fluid" /></div>
      <div class="col-3 text-center mb-2"><img src="//placehold.it/50x50" class="img-fluid" /></div>
      <div class="col-3 text-center mb-2"><img src="//placehold.it/50x50" class="img-fluid" /></div>
      <div class="col-3 text-center mb-2"><img src="//placehold.it/50x50" class="img-fluid" /></div>
      <div class="col-3 text-center mb-2"><img src="//placehold.it/50x50" class="img-fluid" /></div>
      <div class="col-3 text-center mb-2"><img src="//placehold.it/50x50" class="img-fluid" /></div>
      <div class="col-3 text-center mb-2"><img src="//placehold.it/50x50" class="img-fluid" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The first `<div>` element is a column wrapper that supplies information on the breakpoints that will affect the display.  From left to right it is written with the smallest breakpoint (`col-*`) to the largest.  If we were to translate this to something readable it might read:

> At the smallest breakpoint use 6/12 columns. At the medium breakpoint
>   begin using 4/12 columns, and at the large breakpoint use 3/12
>   columns.

**Note**: `col-sm-*` exists but was not used here. Because a 'small' breakpoint was not used Bootstrap will default to the next smallest (in this case `col-6`

Inside the column wrapper we have another wrapper with several classes:

- **.h-100** helps us create equal-height items regardless of whether the
  content dictates a smaller height.
- **.bg-secondary** is a utility class that provides the dark background color
- **.p-4** is a utility class that provides padding on both the X and Y margins (4 indicates the 'level' of padding and can be as low as 0 and as high as 5)

At this point we start seeing the actual content.  Your primary image has several classes that affect its shape and its position:

- **.rounded-circle** is an image thumbnail class that forces a circular border radius.
- **.img-fluid** is a responsive class that helps the image size up and down proportional to the element in which it resides.
- **.d-block** transforms the `img` into a block-level element
- **.mx-auto** sets the X margins to 'auto' which, in combination with `d-block`, centers the image.

From here we reach the 8 button/images referenced in your original post. The Bootstrap Grid is the perfect solution for this sort of organization, but since we're already working with content inside a Grid Element we need to create a new `.row`.

Inside the new `.row` we have a single breakpoint column (`.col-3`) with a couple of utility classes: `text-center` centers the content and `mb-2` sets the bottom margin in a similar way that the `p-*` utility class alters padding.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, really makes me feel good that their are people out there willing to help. I have gotten myself closer and I'm going to continue working on it before I ask something else. I don't actually plan to use the grey boxes/circles, they were just placeholders for images, same with the blue box, just wanted to abstract away the details but I wasn't clear about that, sorry. The whole box with the circle image will be an image and the blue box will be a small icon image directly on top of the bottom image.

Comment: Utilizing the structure I laid out you should be able to swap those placeholder images for something less abstract like actual buttons or icons.